# How to get Firebase crash reporting data on web?

Tags: firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Is there a way to get Firebase crash reporting data for web? I went through the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/) but couldn't find capabilities for web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Crash Reporting is available for iOS and Android. It is not currently available for the web.

If you think there is a good use-case for having the feature on the web, I'd recommend filing a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to weigh in.

Comment: Currently I'm using Firebase Crash Reporting in iOS app. Is there any API to get the crash reporting information to web interface?

Comment: The [Firebase Crash Reporting SDK for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios) can be used to report crashes in your iOS app. This crashes will then show up in the [Crash Reporting tab of your Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/babel-fire/monitoring).